# Simple stemming and lemmatization in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
def check():
    stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
    lemmatizer = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
    temp_sent = "Several women told me I have lying eyes."

    print [stemmer.stem(t) for t in nltk.word_tokenize(temp_sent)]
    print [lemmatizer.lemmatize(t) for t in nltk.word_tokenize(temp_sent)]
```

**Output:**

```
[u'sever', u'women', u'told', 'me', 'i', u'have', u'lie', u'eye', '.']
['Several', u'woman', 'told', 'me', 'I', 'have', 'lying', u'eye', '.']
```

Can someone suggest a better alternative?  Stemmer fails with `several` and lemmatizer with `lying`. I would prefer lemmatizer I have a lot of time to run ,i.e, `accuracy> efficiency`.

Comment: There is no answer if your requirement is  "simple"

Comment: @stark hey thanks for the reply! I meant anyway possible, preferably using using some opensource code.

Comment: Seems like the stemmer works if you add a list of cases where the word ending is not removable. The lemmatizer did a pretty good job. Not sure why it doesn't know lie is the root of lying, but maybe you can add to its database.

Comment: @stark Thanks for the reply! Can you provide some code how to achieve what you said. I am new to nltk.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to try [Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml). There are plenty python wrappers. Usage example of [one of them](https://github.com/Wordseer/stanford-corenlp-python):

```
from corenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
corenlp_dir = "PATH_TO_FOLDER_WITH_JAR"
corenlp = StanfordCoreNLP(corenlp_dir)
corenlp.raw_parse("Several women told me I have lying eyes.")
```

The ouput:

```
{'sentences': [{'parsetree': '[Text=women CharacterOffsetBegin=8 CharacterOffsetEnd=13 PartOfSpeech=NNS Lemma=woman] [Text=told CharacterOffsetBegin=14 CharacterOffsetEnd=18 PartOfSpeech=VBD Lemma=tell] [Text=me CharacterOffsetBegin=19 CharacterOffsetEnd=21 PartOfSpeech=PRP Lemma=I] [Text=I CharacterOffsetBegin=22 CharacterOffsetEnd=23 PartOfSpeech=PRP Lemma=I] [Text=have CharacterOffsetBegin=24 CharacterOffsetEnd=28 PartOfSpeech=VBP Lemma=have] [Text=lying CharacterOffsetBegin=29 CharacterOffsetEnd=34 PartOfSpeech=VBG Lemma=lie] [Text=eyes CharacterOffsetBegin=35 CharacterOffsetEnd=39 PartOfSpeech=NNS Lemma=eye] [Text=. CharacterOffsetBegin=39 CharacterOffsetEnd=40 PartOfSpeech=. Lemma=.] (ROOT (S (NP (JJ Several) (NNS women)) (VP (VBD told) (NP (PRP me)) (SBAR (S (NP (PRP I)) (VP (VBP have) (S (VP (VBG lying) (NP (NNS eyes)))))))) (. .)))', 'text': 'Several women told me I have lying eyes.', 'dependencies': [('root', 'ROOT', '0', 'told', '3'), ('amod', 'women', '2', 'Several', '1'), ('nsubj', 'told', '3', 'women', '2'), ('dobj', 'told', '3', 'me', '4'), ('nsubj', 'have', '6', 'I', '5'), ('ccomp', 'told', '3', 'have', '6'), ('xcomp', 'have', '6', 'lying', '7'), ('dobj', 'lying', '7', 'eyes', '8')], 'words': [('Several', {'CharacterOffsetEnd': '7', 'Lemma': 'several', 'PartOfSpeech': 'JJ', 'CharacterOffsetBegin': '0'})]}]}
```

For sure, it's very verbose, but you can choose options and try to use only lemmatizer or something else, because it's very powerfull set of tools for the most popular nlp tasks.

P.s. You have to download Stanford CoreNLP [from here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-04-20.zip) and write path to the package folder to *corenlp_dir* variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It would be great if you would show an example of stanford nlp with the same sentence in the question. That way it easier to get the efficient way across stated approaches.

Comment: Unfortunately It looks like *raw_parse* doesn't work properly, so It's not so easy to get lemmas for words in input. I've created issue: https://github.com/Wordseer/stanford-corenlp-python/issues/12 . You can also try to work with Stanford CoreNLP via Jython and use required tools directly.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Should I also start the server on my machine to use this package?